# Error after creating exe with Py2exe

Tags: python, wxpython, py2exe

Py2exe seems to run fine although it does mention that a few modules maybe missing.

I had been using the windows option (in my py2exe script) to remove the console window  but realized that the process still remained open even after I closed down the gui window i.e. I could still see the process still in task manager... So I switched to using the console option and found the below error printed there.  I believe this error is preventing the the app from closing. Apart from that the app runs fine.

Iv tried creating an exe from a very simple wxPython GUI app but even then I still get this error however I have no problem creating executables from apps that do not include wxPython.

```
Debug: src/helpers.cpp(140): 'createActCtx' failed with error 0x0000007b (the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.).)
```

[image]

> Python: 2.6.6
>
> wxPython: 2.8.11.0
>
> Windows 7
>
> py2exe: 0.6.9

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import glob



excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'pywin.debugger',
            'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl',
            'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter']

dll_excludes = ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll', 'tk84.dll',]#'msvcp90.dll']

packages = []#'wx.lib.pubsub']


data_files = [("resources", ['resources/1187958_90214884.jpg'])]
packages = ['wx.lib.pubsub',]
options = {'py2exe': {'compressed': 3,
                          'optimize': 2,
                          'excludes': excludes,
                          'packages': packages,
                          'dll_excludes': dll_excludes,
                          'bundle_files': 1,
                          'dist_dir': 'dist',
                          'xref': False,
                          'skip_archive': False,
                          'ascii': False,
                          'packages': packages,
                        'custom_boot_script': '',
                         }
                }  

#windows=[{'script':'gui.py'}]


for script in ["gui.py"]:
    windows=[{
        'script':[script]
    }]

    setup(options=options, console=[script], zipfile=None, data_files=data_files)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had very little trouble getting wxPython code to compile to an exe using py2exe. I have a tutorial that you can try here:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/31/a-py2exe-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/

I have had some issues with the new version of pubsub that is included with 2.8.11.0. You can read the thread here: http://bit.ly/emoHEr

I ended up reverting to the previous version of wx that day mainly because I didn't have time to figure out what I was doing wrong. I don't know if that's the problem that you're having though.

Comment: Thanks mike I, I tried your setup script but I still got the same error. I don't think its pubSub related as I already made corrections to my app as outlined here:[http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.py2exe/4048] (before I did that py2exe would not convert it at all). After some messing around I realized that the console window closes when the console window does when `wx.App.__init__(self)` is not included in the `OnInit()` method. So this seems to be the cause of my problem and not the above mentioned error.

Comment: This is still a problem though as I like to use that call to redirect the sdterror to a file. i.e. `wx.App.__init__(self, redirect=True, filename=appName_errors.log")`

Comment: Hmmm looks like I spoke too soon, I now have that problem aswell. `TypeError: sendMessage() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) `. Are still running `2.8.10.1` ?

Comment: Sorry. SO changed the way they notify me of comments, so I didn't see these until today. Yes, I'm still using 2.8.10.1 at work. You might want to ask on the wxPython mailing list for help on this...or the py2exe list.